# I'd like to make an approximate approximation

Tags: approximation

This is my code:

```
A = 
  {{(9 k3^2 (1 + ν))/
      (9 + 3 c^2 k3^2 (3 + 10 ν + 5 ν^2) + c^4 k3^4 (1 + ν)^2 (3 + 10 ν + 5 ν^2)), 
    -((3 c^2 k3^3 (1 + ν)^2)/
      (9 + 3 c^2 k3^2 (3 + 10 ν + 5 ν^2) + c^4 k3^4 (1 + ν)^2 (3 + 10 ν + 5 ν^2)))}, 
   {(9 k3 (3 + 2 c^2 k3^2 (1 + ν)^2))/
      (c^2 (9 + 3 c^2 k3^2 (3 + 10 ν + 5 ν^2) + c^4 k3^4 (1 + ν)^2 (3 + 10 ν + 5 ν^2))), 
    -((9 k3^2 (1 + ν))/
      (9 + 3 c^2 k3^2 (3 + 10 ν + 5 ν^2) + c^4 k3^4 (1 + ν)^2 (3 + 10 ν + 5 ν^2)))}}
```

I am trying to approximate the expression.

But I don't know how to do this.

The expression tries to approximate the values in the denominator.

The approximate standard would be to remove paragraphs based on k3^2 over in the denominator.

For example:

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for `Series`.

Comment: `Series` is one kind, it may be `PadeApproximant` or an approximation in the frequency domain?. What kind of approximation?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a rule such that k3^n where n>=2 becomes 0 in the denominators. First collect Numerators & Denominators separately:

```
nums = Map[Numerator, A, {2}]

dens = Map[Denominator, A, {2}]
```

Apply the rule to get new denominators

```
dens2 = dens /. k3^(n_ /; n >= 2) -> 0
```

Get the expressions back as ratios of numerators & corresponding new denominators

```
nums/dens2
```